# C# foreach iterating rule for collections

Tags: c#, collections, foreach, iteration

How .NET decides for order of items when iterating through collections ?

For example:

```
list<string> myList = new List<string>();

myList.Add("a");
myList.Add("b");
myList.Add("c");

foreach (string item in myList)
{
    // What's the order of items? a -> b -> c ?
}
```

I need this order (accessing collection members):

```
for (int i = 1; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    string item = myList[i - 1]; // This is the order I need
}
```

Can I safely use `foreach` with `List`? What about other types of collections?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678162/sort-order-when-using-foreach-on-an-array-list-etc

Comment: you right, I didn't find it (voted).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.NET doesn't decide it - the class implementing `IEnumerable` decides how it is being done. For `List` that is from index 0 to the last one. For `Dictionary` it depends on the hash value of the key I think.

`List` indexes are 0 based, so you can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    string item = myList[i]; // This is the order I need
}
```

and is the same result as `foreach`. However if you want to be explicit about it then just stick to the for loop. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: and, of course, if you want a different order, you're free to extend the class and override the method.

Answer (score 2):

I believe foreach starts at the first index and steps though until the last item in the list.

you can safely use foreach although I think it is a little slower than the for i=1; i < myList.count method.

Also, I would say you usually start at index 0. eg:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count -1 ; i++)
{   
 string item = myList[i]; // This is the order I need
}
```

Answer (score 1):

foreach is fine . You should only look into the internals of how a loop works if you are looking for perfomance ( eg a number cruncher ) .

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, use foreach.

```
list myList = new List();

myList.Add("a");
myList.Add("b");
myList.Add("c");

foreach (string item in myList)
{
    // It's in right order! a -> b -> c !
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic List will enumerate in the order of addition, as you suggest. Other implementations of Enumerator may vary, If its important you could consider a SortedList.